# Find $u=u(x,t)$ that solves $u_t=4u_{xxt}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

> Find $u=u(x,t)$ that solves $u_t=4u_{xxt}$

I am not sure where to begin with. Can someone find me an example to solve this or a hint is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: This is the same as solving the ODE

$$4u'' - u = f(x)$$

for an arbitrary inhomogenous function of $x$ since

$$4u_{xxt} - u_t = (4u_{xx} - u)_t = 0$$